# Dealing with class inheritance in python

Tags: python, inheritance

Can someone explain why I'm getting the error:

```
global name 'helloWorld' is not defined
```

when executing the following:

```
class A:
    def helloWorld():
        print 'hello world'

class B(A):
    def displayHelloWorld(self):
        helloWorld()

class Main:
     def main:
        b = B()
        b.displayHelloWorld()
```

I'm used to java where class B would obviously have a copy of class A's method "helloWorld" and thus this code would run fine when executing main.  This however appears to think class B doesn't have any method called "helloWorld"

Comment: What do you think would happen if you called `helloworld` from another method in A? The answer should show you that this has nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: what version of python do You use?

Comment: This code is chock full of errors before you can even get to this point (like `def main:`), and it has no code that actually calls the method in question, and your error message is not an actual Python error message. If you want people to debug your code for you, you really need to give the actual code and the actual bugs, not just something vaguely similar that we have to guess at.

Answer (score 6):

Missing the self before the helloWorld(). The self keyword means that this an instance function or variable. When class B inherits class A, all the functions in class A can now be accessed with the `self.classAfunction()` as if they were implemented in class B.

```
class A():
    def helloWorld(self): # <= missing a self here too
        print 'hello world'

class B(A):
    def displayHelloWorld(self):
        self.helloWorld()

class Main():
     def main(self):
        b = B()
        b.displayHelloWorld()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to indicate that the method is from that class (`self.`):

```
class B(A):
    def displayHelloWorld(self):
        self.helloWorld()
```

Python differs in this from Java. You have to specify this explicitly in Python whereas Java accepts implicitly as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the version of python used in this example but it seems that syntax looks like python3. (except `print` statement which looks like python2.x)

Lets suppose that this is python3

I would say that `helloWorld` is class method of class `A` and It should be called as class attribute. As soon as this function is in class namespace It can be accessed outside this class only using owner class.

```
A.helloWorld()
```

or

```
B.helloWorld()
```

or

```
self.__class__.helloWorld()
```

You can't call it as bound method in this case because `self` argument will be passed and as soon as your function doesn't expect it it will fail.

there is possibility that `helloWorld` is method of `A` and `self` parameter is just missed

in this case this method can be called as follow:

```
self.helloWorld()
```

or

```
A.helloWorld(self)
```